# Quartz Scheduler not working in OpenShift

Tags: openshift, quartz-scheduler

I have pushed the quartz scheduler configuration to OpenShift application that was working on local Tomcat server. I have verified that its reading from the quartz.properties file from main/resources folder. Here is the logs and the code. I changed the schedule of the job to fire after a few minutes i push the code.

```
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    try {
        // Setup the Job class and the Job group
        JobDetail job = newJob(DailyUpdates.class).withIdentity("CronQuartzJob", "Group").build();

        // Create a Trigger that fires every 10 minutes.
        Trigger trigger = newTrigger()
                .withIdentity("TriggerName", "Group")
                .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.dailyAtHourAndMinute(8, 55))
                .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.dailyAtHourAndMinute(18, 0))
                .build();

        // Setup the Job and Trigger with Scheduler & schedule jobs
        scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
        scheduler.start();
        scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
    } catch (SchedulerException ex) {
        logger.error(ex);
    }

}
```

Log file says:

```
2016-05-10 08:52:54 INFO  QuartzScheduler:240 - Quartz Scheduler v.2.2.3 created.
2016-05-10 08:52:54 INFO  QuartzScheduler:2311 - JobFactory set to: org.quartz.simpl.SimpleJobFactory@8c6fdb
2016-05-10 08:52:54 INFO  RAMJobStore:155 - RAMJobStore initialized.
2016-05-10 08:52:54 INFO  QuartzScheduler:305 - Scheduler meta-data: Quartz Scheduler (v2.2.3) 'CustomQuartzScheduler' with instanceId 'NON_CLUSTERED'
  Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.
  NOT STARTED.
  Currently in standby mode.
  Number of jobs executed: 0
  Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 5 threads.
  Using job-store 'org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore' - which does not support persistence. and is not clustered.

2016-05-10 08:52:54 INFO  StdSchedulerFactory:1327 - Quartz scheduler 'CustomQuartzScheduler' initialized from default resource file in Quartz package: 'quartz.properties'
2016-05-10 08:52:54 INFO  StdSchedulerFactory:1331 - Quartz scheduler version: 2.2.3
2016-05-10 08:52:54 INFO  QuartzScheduler:575 - Scheduler CustomQuartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED started.
2016-05-10 08:52:54 DEBUG QuartzSchedulerThread:276 - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
2016-05-10 08:52:54 DEBUG QuartzSchedulerThread:276 - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
2016-05-10 08:53:18 DEBUG QuartzSchedulerThread:276 - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
2016-05-10 08:53:46 DEBUG QuartzSchedulerThread:276 - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
2016-05-10 08:54:41 DEBUG QuartzSchedulerThread:276 - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
2016-05-10 08:55:05 DEBUG QuartzSchedulerThread:276 - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
2016-05-10 08:55:31 DEBUG QuartzSchedulerThread:276 - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
```

And the properties file:

```
org.quartz.scheduler.skipUpdateCheck = true
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = CustomQuartzScheduler
org.quartz.scheduler.jobFactory.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleJobFactory
org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Trigger was not reading from multiple schedules. I had to create multiple triggers each with its own schedule and it started working.